# PBR Frensel effect

Tags: graphics, 3d, rendering, pbr

I'm read Real-Time Rendering and the Radiometry section was too hard for me to understand, so I googled PBR and found [this](https://www.marmoset.co/toolbag/learn/pbr-theory) article.

Can someone explain the next sentence?

> The second observation about Fresnel properties is that the curve or
>   gradient between the angles does not vary much from material to
>   material. Metals are the most divergent, but they too can be accounted
>   for analytically.

Secondly, I'm really new to PBR. Can you recommend other good articles about this subject, with a focus on coding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "gradient between the angles" the author is talking about a a simple 2D function: Reflectivity(theta).  As mentioned in the previous paragraph, for ALL materials, Reflectivity(theta) tends towards 100% as the theta tends towards 90 degrees.  That is, ALL materials behave like a perfect mirror when the grazing angle is 90 degrees.

However, the in-between values of Reflectivity(theta) may be different for wood, metal, concrete, etc.  Again, think of the 2D graph mapping theta to reflectivity.  They would have different ease-in and ease-out behaviors, to use an animation analogy.

See the graph below that sentence, and replace "Center" and "Edge" with 0 and 90.

What the author means by "accounted for analytically" is that we don't need to store the exact curve (either in a lookup texture or array) -- we can compute Fresnel with a formula ("analytically") using other values in the material.

Here is an article about Fresnel by John Hable.  He writes good articles with shader codes, especially about color correction and skin:

http://filmicgames.com/archives/557

This is not about PBR, but about storing your 1D falloff functions instead of computing analytically (the opposite of above).  Maybe it will be interesting:

http://c0de517e.blogspot.com/2013/12/never-again-point-lights.html

Answer (score 1):

As per the answer above, the sentence refer to the function representing the behavior of the energy bounce (due to reflection) as a function of the angle.
This curve is shared between many materials and starts gradually at a linear slope before starting to converge toward 1.0 (hence complete reflection) as it approaches 90 degrees - typically the curve will start to converge aroun 60-70 degrees.

Note that for metals this function is more diverse and does expose different behavior - this is very evident for iron which in effect reflects less around 70 degrees before converging back again - google fresnel reflection or IOR for metallic materials to inspect this behavior.

Good references will be the Siggraph 2010 / 2012 and 2015 presented by Brent Burley of Disney - here is 2012 which gives a good summary of the subject - notice that some of Burley's equations are artistically chosen (diffuse approximation near the rims) as he mentions:

https://disney-animation.s3.amazonaws.com/library/s2012_pbs_disney_brdf_notes_v2.pdf